# Are the limit points of $[0, 1)$ and $(0, 1)$ the same?

Tags: analysis

I am currently in a real analysis class using Rudin's PMA. In class, the professor presented some examples of sets and stated whether they were open, closed, and/or bounded.

It was stated in class that $[0, 1)$ is not open because $1$ is a limit point and $1$ is not in the set, while $(0, 1)$ is open because $0$ and $1$ are limit points and they are in the set.

However, it seemed to me that he was implying that $0$ was not a limit point. Is this true?

My intuition is that a point $p$ on the "boundary" of a set is a limit point when some parts of some neighborhood $N_r(p)$ are included in the set, so $0$ would be a limit point. Is there a better way of thinking about limit points intuitively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second paragraph you are confusing open and closed.  A set is closed if it contains its limit points.  $[0,1)$ is not closed because $1$ is a limit point and not in the set.  $(0,1)$ is not closed because both $0$ and $1$ are limit points not in the set.  Yes, $0$ is a limit point of $(0,1)$.  There are points in $(0,1)$ arbitrarily close to $0$.

A set is open if every point as a neighborhood that is in the set.  $(0,1)$ is open because every point has an interval containing it that is within $(0,1)$.  $[0,1)$ is not open because $0$ does not have a neighborhood that is within the set because all neighborhoods of $0$ include some negative numbers.

The answer to your title question is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Just think that $a$ is a limit point iff there is a sequence $(x_n)$ of elements of the set with $x_n\neq a$ such that $(x_n)$ converges to $a$. So, 0 and 1 are limit points of $(0,1)$ and $[0,1)$. Just take the sequences $(x_n)=(1/n)$ for $a=0$ and $(y_n)=(1-1/n)$ for $a=1$.